# Diagram frame background color in Enterprise Architect (15.2)

Tags: enterprise-architect

When creating some diagram in Enterprise Architect, it is an easy task to modify all blocks within the diagram, even the background color of the page itself. But I completely fail in finding the setting to change the background color of the actual frame itself. Is it really that hidden?

Sidemark: when changing theme also this color changes, so there must be something...

[image: definition of bg color]

UPDATE: when selecting the diagram, I would expect the background color to be modified when using the toolbox, I can change frame color, text color, line width, but not bg color. Probably a bug...

[image: expected functionality]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was deceived and thought this were boundaries. But they are diagram frames. And these do not have coloring. I thought about applying a different Theme to the underying diagram, but that is not inherited by the frame. I tried using a colored boundary as background but that will not fill the whole frame:

[image]

So basically: you're out of luck here. You might send a feature request. But you need a veeeery long breath.